# How to use Spring Integration Aggregator for 'look-ahead' releasing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

### The problem

I'm developing an application with Spring Integration (version `5.0.0.M2` as I need dynamic flow registration feature) and at some point I have to aggregate messages according to their `correlationId` header. The header marks some continuous subsequences among the messages, i.e. it changes just when a new subsequence starts. The aim of the aggregator is to convert subsequences into individual 'grouped' messages.
The source of messages is external and unpredictable so that it can't provide the emitted messages with `sequenceSize` header. As a consequence, the decision whether to release current accumulating group cannot be made until the next message comes with another `correlationId` header (or there is no next message for a `timeout` ms which means the end of the input). Partial releasing is unacceptable.

The **problem** is that Spring Integration `ReleaseStrategy` is designed to release only *currently* accumulating group (including current message) while my task requires to 'look ahead' for a next message to find out if current group is complete or not. The same problem from the next message's point of view may be considered 'look-back' releasing.

So the **question** is: is there a way to release a message group from the aggregator basing on the next message's header (not including the latter)?

### Tried solution

I've researched the source code of `org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler` and the only workaround I've found by the moment is a quite dirty trick - I've inherited from `AggregatingMessageHandler` and overridden `handleMessageInternal` method. In the method I compare current message's `correlationId` with one saved on the previous invocation. If it differs I extract previous group from the store and call `forceComplete` with it. Then (in any way) I delegate current message processing to parent's `handleMessageInternal` method. Here's the code snippet:

```java
  @Override
  protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    Long currentGroupId = message.getHeaders().get(CORRELATION_ID, Long.class);

    boolean needToReleasePreviousGroup = ((previousGroupId != null) && !previousGroupId.equals(currentGroupId));
    if (needToReleasePreviousGroup) {
      MessageGroup previousGroup = getMessageStore().getMessageGroup(previousGroupId);
      if (previousGroup.size() != 0) {
        forceComplete(previousGroup);
      } else {
        log.debug("Previous group with id={} has been already released. Skip.", previousGroupId);
      }
    }

    super.handleMessageInternal(message);
    previousGroupId = currentGroupId;   // do unconditionally as we'll check that group on the next step anyway
  }
```

I realize that this solution makes the aggregator itself stateful (while it shouldn't be) and not applicable for many other scenarios. Furthermore, it makes the applied code coupled with the internals of the framework.

I'd be glad if someone point me to a better solution. I'm open to provide additional details about the problem or the solution I've used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your `previousGroupId` solution and your description as:

> 'look ahead' for a next message to find out if current group is complete or not.

The "current" word is a key here.

So, that means for me that your aggregator is `single group` and you have to release the current state and start a new one based on the state of the current message.

For this purpose I'd make an aggregator really as single-grouped - the `correlationStrategy` should return some constant, e.g. `1`.

To release or not the current group is really a `ReleaseStrategy` responsibility. The latest message will be really the last one in the `MessageGroup.getMessages()`. So, you reach that message, decide if you need to release or not and move on to the custom `MessageGroupProcessor` to produce the cumulative result from the aggregator.

In that `MessageGroupProcessor` you *remove* the latest "guilty" message do not include it into the result and send it back to the aggregator to form a fresh message group.

Does it make sense to you ?

Comment: yes, it seems what I need. But I still can't see how to '_send it back to the aggregator_'? Doing it directly from the `MessageGroupProcessor` is senseless as the current group is not released yet. Doing it by means of some asynchronous resubmitting to the aggregator's input channel seems to me like increasing application's complexity and producing excess work. Is there a more clean way to resubmit a message to the aggregator (or any other message handler)?

Comment: That's true. You have to send that message to the `QueueChannel` for thread shifting and letting the current thread to release the group and clean resources. The poller on that queue won't be able to place that message to the aggregator until the lock for the `correlationKey` isn't released.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to apply this approach. Locking on `correlationKey` is the puzzle's part I haven't taken into count while imaging how would it work. I'll share the results as soon as I get them.

Comment: Pay attention that you can inject `LockRegistry` into aggregator and can use the same `lock` in other place.

Comment: Thank you very much, Artem! Your solution proved to be the one I was looking for. It took some time for me to make it work and the most of this time I've spent trying to write a unit or integration test for the new couple of components (queue and aggregator). Suddenly it turned out to be a very sophisticated problem. I eventually found [respective ticket on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/23) and I hope it will soon transform into comprehensive testing solution.

Comment: Ha! As you see there is a PoC on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2053. I would like to include something into the current Milestone for the end of the month. But nay feedback and ideas would be great first of all.

Comment: I've [added a comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2053#issuecomment-287130598) to the issue with my proposal of what would be helpful in cases like I encountered in this question.

Answer (score 0):

For those who try to solve the same or similar problem there's a [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/Toparvion/348c184ca7797d749ece33329da74e7c) containing source code of the aggregator configuration built basing on the accepted answer.

The source code is intentionally simplified for the question. The real one is able additionally to release groups either by timeout or by group size threshold. Ready to share it as well if needed.